# php laravel eloquent object can not be changed

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach

I have a weird bug, I dont know why it will not work. So I am using Laravel php framework and getting from db a object. Since some decimal number looks like this : '.00', I want to change it to this '0', but it cannot be changed when I loop through it.
It looks like this:

```
 $stipendien = Stipendium::where('id','=',$request->input('id'))->get()->toArray();


        
        foreach($stipendien as $object => $test)
        {
            foreach($test as $key => $value)
            {
                if($test[$key] == ".00")
                {
                    $test[$key] = "0";
                }
            }
        }
return $stipendien;
```

Should not the '$stipendien' be changed when I assign the value new, since it does go to the if statement and getting the correct key ?

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:17 [
    "id" => 1
    "Kosten_Kurs" => "22.00"
    "Kosten_Prüfung" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Unterlagen" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Lernurlaub" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Reise" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Sonstig" => ".00"

  ]
  1 => array:17 [
    "id" => 2
    "Kosten_Kurs" => "22.00"
    "Kosten_Prüfung" => "2.00"
    "Kosten_Unterlagen" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Lernurlaub" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Reise" => ".00"
    "Kosten_Sonstig" => ".00"
  ]
]
```

But when I return it, it did not change at all. What did I wrong here?

Comment: Are you changing/updating `$stipendien` anywhere?

Comment: wouldnt `$stipendien` be changed, when I use the key and value iteration like this?

Comment: No, simplified, you take "_the contents_" of `$stipendien[0]` and changed that. `$stipendien[0]` itself stays untouched

Comment: Thank you! I really thought it would be changed and was confused like hell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using this in loop while assigning 0

```
 $stipendien[$object][$key] = "0";
```

Answer (score 3):

check that your condition is matched by adding dd() or die inside this if

```
if($test[$key] == ".00")
{
   $test[$key] = "0";
}
```

Comment: hey! Yes it does die inside

Comment: try updating with $stipendien[$object][$key] = "0";

Comment: Thanks! It works! I thought it would change the object anyway when I loop through it...